# If a WiFi client disassociates from the router, can the router re-establish connection or can only the client do it?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I set up a Debian server on an Intel NUC that runs Apache and Samba. It's only connected via WiFi via a static IP. I noticed in the server's kernel log that the WiFi connection (iwlwifi) is disassociated from the router when the router senses no activity from the NUC's WiFi connection.

The problem with this is there's no way to ping the server once this happens, and I know of no way to re-establish the WiFi connection without doing it *from the server itself using the keyboard* (i.e. pinging the router brings the connection back up).

Is this normal behavior? If so, this means the WiFi connection will eventually disconnect and will never reconnect because I don't think there's anything running on the server that sends regular network requests.

Is there any way to fix this other than to use cron to ping the router at regular intervals?

**UPDATE:**

It appears the problem was the router. I am using a Linksys WRT3200ACM running OpenWRT, and this router apparently has known issues with WiFi due to its Marvell chipset and open source Linux driver. I put an access point on the network with a MediaTek WiFi chip (bypassing the Linksys' WiFi), and the connection problems went away.

So the takeaway here is don't expect stable WiFi performance with a WRT3200ACM when running open source firmware.

Comment: You seem to have a problem with the router. I would guess that you may ping it from any device to wake it up, not only from Debian. Search for a firmware update for the router, or if one doesn't exist then do a factory reset (warning: user settings will be lost).

Comment: Your “update” should be posted as an answer and you should check it off as an answer because it is the answer.

Comment: While it's tempting to run OpenWrt on the WRT3200ACM or WRT32X, if they're going to be used for WiFi, it's more problems than it's worth _(I have both running OpenWrt, but use my WRT1900ACS for WiFi since it's only Marvell's driver on the 3200ACM/32X that isn't stable. Background: miscommunication occurred between Linksys and Marvell about the opensourcing of the radio driver, Linksys jumped the gun and marketed both as the driver being opensource without Marvell opensourcing it yet, and that's how things have remained since both were RTM'd; WiFi will likely never be stable on either)_

Answer (score 1):

Joining or re-joining a Wi-Fi network is always up to the client device. There is no way for a router (AP) to initiate it.

All Wi-Fi client devices have their own software that manages the state of the Wi-Fi connection and automatically reconnect when they get disconnected for a "non-fatal" reason. If that is not happening on your Linux box, you should troubleshoot your Linux Wi-Fi subsystems. For example, I could imagine a misconfigured wpa_supplicant might cause the problem you're seeing. Or possibly a buggy wireless driver.